# Need to Edit Pivoted JS grid

Tags: jquery

I have a pivoted gird which has two panes left and right. Right pane is pivoted and only has numeric values. I need to make the whole js grid editable on page load.
I have set the editable = true in view. cs and left pane of the grid is editable.

The data entry is column wise for e.g. left side has product name and right pane has quantity(pivoted column)
Please assist on how can I make pivoted columns as editable.

Please let me know if more information is required.
Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Maybe you should start by posting what have you done so far...

Comment: Thanks for your response Toni...

I have tried making grid fields editable. 
Other option I have is to specify the editable property by calling OOB method: SP.JsGrid.PropertyType.RegisterNewCustomPropType(in GridColumn.js) , however I am not ware on how to achieve this.

Comment: Also, I get below error when I click on any cell in pivoted grids: "Assertion Failed: Edit Control named needs to be registered before being instantiated"

Comment: Please edit the question and add your current code if you want some help http://stackoverflow.com/tour